# How to set end date as a current or today's date in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, meanjs

all I want to filter the items like (Start and End Date)  which are based on `invoice_date` using the date range functionality in meanjs app.

- My problem is the date filter function are working perfectly in `plunker and my localHost production` but  while pushing to server it's showing only up to `May month` data's if some `invoice_date` values date has been `2017-08-24 and 2017-07-27' these data is not displaying in table, I don't know where I did the mistake and what I have missed it ..... [My Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/1dYcIrkdnFxri8yUZPk6?p=preview)
- Please look at my plunker to reference.
- I Have displaying `invoice_date`, so this is the field I want to use for filtering.
- So what I exactly looking for, I want to filter the `invoice_date` as start date and end date : **for example:-** if we select start date like `24-05-2017` and end date is `24-08-2017` in table this two transaction only need to display or filter... so I have used date range filter to achieve this solution, but in server it's not working for us please help.
- In my server if I select `end date` as today's date all data's are showing perfectly on the table, so I think the problem is based on these fields `$scope.from = new Date(2014, 04, 30);
  $scope.to = new Date(2019, 08, 25);`
- So if We set `end date` as a `current or today's` date in default, I think
  the problem would be solved, so how to set today's date as a default to `end date`...

**Controller:**

```
 .filter('dateRange', function() {
    return function(records, dateKey, from, to) {
        return records.filter(function(record) {
            return !moment(record[dateKey], 'YYYY-MM-DD').isBefore(moment(from))
            && !moment(record[dateKey], 'YYYY-MM-DD').isAfter(moment(to));
        });
    };
})
```

**Html:**

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="from" ng-model="from">

<input type="date" class="form-control" name="to" ng-model="to" ng-bind="getDatetime | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'">
```

**Filter:-**

```
ng-repeat="data in  record | dateRange : 'invoice_date' : from : to"
```

- I tried the `ng-bind` method to set default today's date to end date like following:-

**In controller:-**

```
$scope.getDatetime = new Date();
```

**In Html:-**

```
<lable>End Date</lable><input type="date" class="form-control" name="to" ng-bind="getDatetime | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" ng-model="to">
```

- I have created plunker for reference:- [My plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1dYcIrkdnFxri8yUZPk6?p=preview)

  - Showing like the moment is not defined:-

[image]

Comment: Your plunker seems to be working fine. I guess the issue might be in the date formats. Are you using the same date format in your server side?

Comment: yes, how to set `current date` into `end date` bcoz in server-side if I have select current date, all data's are displaying perfectly to me....

Comment: Are you looking for something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/EGzDNRzPyTwwKeNjSRXI?p=preview ?

Comment: Yes exactly but this is also not working in my web portal.... showing error like the `moment is not defined`...

Comment: Have you included moment.js ? Check if all the dependencies for moment.js are there

Comment: Yes but again showing same error, and Vivz if you don't mind can you help this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45982486/how-to-remove-empty-values-in-drop-down-using-ng-option-in-angular-js question, please....