# How to use filter with in ng-repeat using Angular js?

Tags: html, angularjs, meanjs

All I want to filter some values with in `ng-repeat`, I have tried but haven't got a solution...

- [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iOADEDTPYKDNuTu9QgGt?p=preview).
- I am looking for three kinds of solution,

(i) In my plunker first, i am looking to filter `ng-module="request_role"` value of `parent` in the list. so I had tried like `| filter: request_role.[parent']`.

(ii) In my plunker second list, i am looking to filter `ng-module="request_role"` value of `Change Agent`. so I had tried like `| filter: request_role.['Change Agentent']`.

(i) In my plunker third list, i am looking to filter `ng-module="request_role"` value of `parent,Change Agent`. so I had tried like `| filter: request_role.['parent,Change Agent']`.

- I think I have done a mistake in `filter`, so please check and update my plunker as well to know exact solution, thanks...

**My Html:-**

```
<p style="background: black;color:white">1.Filter request_role  value of `parent` data's in below list</p>
        <div  ng-repeat="question in users | filter: request_role.['parent']">
            <small>
              <table border="0">
                <tbody>
                  <th>{{question.displayName}}</th>
                <th style="background: yellow;">,{{question.roles[0]}}</th>
                <th style="background: light;">,{{question.request_role[0]}}</th>

                </tbody>
                      </table>


              </small>
        </div>

        <p style="background: black;color:white">2. Filter request_role  value of `Change Agent ` data's in below list</p>
        <div  ng-repeat="question in users | filter: request_role.['Change Agent']">
            <small>
              <table border="0">
                <tbody>
                  <th>{{question.displayName}}</th>
                <th style="background: yellow;">,{{question.roles[0]}}</th>
                <th style="background: light;">,{{question.request_role[0]}}</th>

                </tbody>
                      </table>


              </small>
        </div>

         <p style="background: black;color:white">3.Filter request_role  Both value of ["parent","Change Agent"] data's in below list</p>
        <div  ng-repeat="question in users | filter: request_role.['parent,Change Agent']">
            <small>
              <table border="0">
                <tbody>
                  <th>{{question.displayName}}</th>
                <th style="background: yellow;">,{{question.roles[0]}}</th>
                <th style="background: light;">,{{question.request_role[0]}}</th>

                </tbody>
                      </table>


              </small>
        </div>
```

**My filter:-**

```
  1. | filter: request_role.['parent']

    2.  | filter: request_role.['Change Agent']

3. | filter: request_role.['parent,Change Agent']
```

- [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RbLqGBrP0ej3Tx7naGol?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using a custom filter or directly by applying a filter on `ng-repeat` as shown below

1. `<div  ng-repeat="question in users | filter: {'request_role':'parent'}">`
2. `<div  ng-repeat="question in users | filter: {'request_role':'Change Agent'}">`
3. `<div  ng-repeat="question in users | filter: {'request_role':'Change Agent','request_role':'parent'}">`

**Working Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/NY3h8BCQn4gAbJsdyiJw?p=preview

Comment: thanks for your answer, your filter is working perfectly based on `values like-  `Change Agent, parent,` but what we expecting the `filter` should base on `ng-module`, not a value. values are not to be constant we just gave example values in plunker, so how we do filter base on `ng-module`   `request_role` .... values are not constant thanks....thank you so much for your help..

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. Do you mean ng-model?

Comment: But where is your ng-model in the above plunker?

Comment: we have not mentioned ng-model in plunker, I just want to filter only this model `request_role`  not with values...

Comment: I don't still understand your requirement. You cannot filter something based on request_role without giving values. But if you want to filter based on an ng-model like ng-model="val.request_role", then you can do something like this <div  ng-repeat="question in users | filter: {'request_role': val.request_role }"> where val.request_role  can be 'parent','Change Agent' etc i.e the values that request_role from your object array can contain